# What are the bumps on the Vega rocket

Tags: identify-this-object, esa, vega

In the image below, we see some bumps at the conical section of what I believe is the transition from the first to the second stage.

What function do they serve?

[image: A photo of the Vega rocket]

Image credit: [Wikimedia Commons](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Vega_and_Sentinel-2_ready_for_launch.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closer view:
[image]
(Cropped from [here](https://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/SC14660.jpg))

They are retro-rockets used in the stage separation system.

[image]

[Source](http://www.spaceflight101.net/vega-info.html)

A CFD image of the thrusters firing:

[image]

[Source](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?db_key=AST&bibcode=2011ESASP.692E.106G&letter=E&classic=YES&defaultprint=YES&whole_paper=YES&page=106&epage=106&send=Send%20PDF&filetype=.pdf)

Comment: Seems kind of pointless, is there a specific reason they explain for the system to exist in the first place? Is there a reason they can't delay X seconds for the vessels to drift apart?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn read the first paragraph in the last link in my answer. My summary of it: For some reason the aerodynamics at staging tended to push the two bodies together.

Comment: Took a quote: "The separatation of the first stage is one of the most critical phases of the flight of every single body launcher beacause it happens at relatively low altitude and as a consequence the forward body is subjected to non-negligible aerodynamic forces which tend to bring the two bodies together again [before significant separation occurs]." if you want to include it :). That was a good read. The conclusion says what I expected, "we did it because we researched it and thought we should!" I didn't actually expect it to not have function was just wondering in general.

Answer (score 4):

Supplemental to Organic Marble's answer, this is what the interstage looks like underneath the covers:

[image]

(found somewhere on the CapcomEspace website, but I can't find the exact page any more)